# removing reflection in plastic for final rendering

Tags: texturing, node-editor, edit-mode, image, reflection

[image]

My boss wants it completely free of all reflections. I can get them off the top piece and I removed it to work on the power supply and the ethernet box. It is the reflections in the glass I need to remove. I added pictures of the lighting and the nodes I used for the transparent part.
I need to get the reflections of the stuff inside off the edges of the plastic. How can I do that?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi, please [add images](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/201046/edit) of the material setup as well as the lighting setup so that others can better asses what the exact issue is. You can markup your images slightly (please no text as it is not searchable in images) to point out what you are referring to as well, and you may also add blend files via [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) Thanks :)

Comment: Is this the same question you asked before? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/200948/how-to-remove-glare-and-brighten-up-the-photo

Comment: I had asked for a different type of glare issue. Now its the reflection of the insides on the sides of the box.

Comment: I dont know how to add photos in comments but I edited my question

Comment: I am at a loss. I have tried so many different node set ups. This is going into my bosses brochure for his product.

Comment: "the reflections of the stuff inside off the edges of the plastic", could you please highlight what you're referring to? hard to guess

Comment: the edges of the glass at the top has the reflection of the ethernet and the power supply in it.

Comment: My boss wants the glass edges to be completely free of all reflections.

Comment: can I make the glass and the box two separate objects and take the reflections away some how?

Comment: Is this not as simple as just changing the Glossy color to black and replacing the Glass shader with a Refraction shader node? That would surely remove all reflections from surfaces.

Comment: Oh. Hang about. Do you mean the apparent reflection in the side of the glass cover? If so, that's not actually a reflection but is a *refraction* - due to your glass cover not having 'thickness' and only being a single surface (so it's as if the whole inside is solid glass). Give it some thickness (either extrude it or just add a Solidify modifier) and that apparent reflection will disappear.

Comment: How thick should I make it?

Comment: you are a genius thank you soooo much!!!!!

Comment: You’re welcome - glad I could help. I’ve added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The apparent reflection in the side of the glass cover is not actually a reflection but is a refraction - due to your glass cover not having 'thickness' and only being a single surface (so it's as if the whole inside is solid glass). Give it some thickness (either extrude it or just add a Solidify modifier) and that apparent reflection will disappear.